# ¿Se puede extraer los datos de una celda en jqgrid usando el método getcell en un evento de doble click?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Para realizar la aplicación estoy usando eclipse, conexión a base de datos Sql server 2008 etc.

El problema es ese cuando uso por ejemplo un `getRowdata` pasándole la `rowid` el valor sale siempre `undefined`.

Si uso `getcell` pasándole como parámetros el rowid y la columna que es también me pasa igual.

En cambio con el evento `onClick` me sale todo perfecto, pero no me vale

Según leí hay un problema cuando las filas son editables y queremos extraer los datos de ella.

¿Alguién sabe la manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Hola @Manueline si es posible que nos muestres lo que has intentado por ahora para así facilitarnos el funcionamiento del código y poder ayudarte

Comment: ¿Podría estar el asunto relacionado con la declaración de addRowData?:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113913/jqgrid-getrowdata-returns-wrong-result